# Return First/Last row in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a MS Access 2013 Query from my companies DB and am having some issues (screenshot included). For column name `Event_Type` if it is `= 2` then I want the first value and the last value(of the whole row) to be returned and cut out the middle ones. Event Type 2 is tracking information and I only want the Odometer reading and cut out the middle fodder. But this needs to be done for each `DRIVER_ID` on each `CREATED` Date.

[image: Sample View of Access Query]

Comment: I tried using the summary option for a new Query based on this one but it wouldnt let me itemize the results to return the first and last of that value.

Comment: I also just tried creating a table out of the data(wont be extremely efficient) to sort the data in the table but not working either I am going to read on some IF functions more.

Comment: This is my thinking for the If Function

If [EVENT_TYPE]= 2, Return first[EVENT_TYPE] for each [Driver_ID] and [Created] and Return last [EVENT_TYPE] for each [Driver_ID] and [Created], else do nothing.